# return null notificationId in NotificationHub

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I use Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs in VS2017. when I try to send a notification by SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync method this doesn't return notificationId, this is null.  I have the Standard pricing for Notification Hub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFjTy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Test Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530751.aspx) by any chance? Please note that NotificationId is returned NULL while doing a test send. This is because you can get the result of Send operation in the output of Send* method itself. NotificationOutcome.Results property will have list of registrations this Send* was sent to. (Note that test sends are only meant for troubleshooting purposes and they target a maximum of 10 devices. Read through the above post for more info).

Comment: No, I'm not using Test Send
I do understand that the tests are only sent to 10. Only that already in my code when using the library does not return the complete information

Answer (score 0):

I worked with REST API I did a simple test and it worked correctly [Send an APNS Native Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223266.aspx), [azure-notificationhubs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples) here I found everything necessary for my problem